# getting random result with symfony many to many relationship

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I have many to many relationship in my doctrine entity with to entities Question and Game.

I want to get one question of a game randomly

Now i can get questions of a game with this syntax `$game->getQuestions()` but it is not give me a random question it just give me all questions of a game

Comment: I think you should use a filter function

Answer (score 1):

There are generally two solutions:

1. If the number of available questions your `Game` model is not that big, just add a method to it, and randomly pick a question from the `Question` `ArrayCollection`.
2. If there are a lot and a lot of `Question` inside your `Game`, then your best bet is to write a custom `Query` inside a custom `Repository` to fetch a random question associated with your `Game`.

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html and http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html

Answer (score 0):

Not good code, but working :

Assuming your questions is a `\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection`

```
$questions = $game->getQuestions()->toArray();
shuffle($questions);
$randomQuestion = array_shift($questions);
```

If there's a lot of questions, you can do a custom query with a random offset between 0 and n-1 (n = how many question you have for this game)